# Matricial Cauchy-Euler equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

It's well-known how to find, in theory, solutions to a Cauchy-Euler equation $$a_kt^k x^{(k)}(t)+\cdots + a_1tx'(t)+a_0x(t)=0:$$one sets $x(t)=t^p$, plug that into the equation, solves a (polynomial) characteristic equation for $p$, and proceeds from there looking at the multiplicities of the roots. I believe I ran into a matrix version of that in $\Bbb R^n$: $$t^k A_k {\bf x}^{(k)}(t)+\cdots+tA_1{\bf x}'(t)+A_0{\bf x}(t) = {\bf 0},$$where the $A_i$ are square $n\times n$ matrices. Is there any known general method to attack this? Thanks.